# $Z$ coordinates disappear in the general rotation transformation matrix.

Tags: matrices, transformation, 3d

I wanted to generate the general rotation transformation matrix ($3D$).

But when I did the multiplication the result didn't include the original $Z$ coordinates,I don't know why the $Z$ disappeared.

$$
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix} \cos  \alpha  & -\sin  \alpha  & 0 \\ \sin  \alpha  & \cos  \alpha  & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix} \cos  \beta  & 0 & \sin  \beta  \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -\sin  \beta  & 0 & \cos  \beta  \end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos  \theta  & -\sin  \theta  \\ 0 & \sin  \theta  & \cos  \theta  \end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \\ Z \end{bmatrix}= \\
&\begin{bmatrix} x\cos  \left( \alpha  \right) \cos  \left( \beta  \right) +y\left( -\sin  \left( \alpha  \right) \cos  \left( \theta  \right) +\sin  \left( \beta  \right) \sin  \left( \theta  \right) \cos  \left( \alpha  \right)  \right)  \\ x\sin  \left( \alpha  \right) \cos  \left( \beta  \right) +y\left( \sin  \left( \alpha  \right) \sin  \left( \beta  \right) \sin  \left( \theta  \right) +\cos  \left( \alpha  \right) \cos  \left( \theta  \right)  \right)  \\ -x\sin  \left( \beta  \right) +y\sin  \left( \theta  \right)  \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align}
$$

As you can see I multiplied the transformation matrix by the order $X,Y,Z$ and then I multiplied it by by the variables of the coordinates of the point.

But the result don't have the $Z$ coordinates,does this mean that the $Z$ coordinates doesn't affect the rotation?
And how can I include the $Z$ in the equation?

Comment: I think alpha and beta are missing from the original matrices

Comment: Sorry,Solved it.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix isn't quite correct (Or it is simplified erroneously), the result of multiplying out the rotation matrices in that specific order is actually
$$R(\alpha,\beta, \theta)=R_Z(\alpha) \cdot R_Y(\beta) \cdot R_X(\theta) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\alpha \cos{\beta}}&\cos{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\sin{\theta}-\sin{\alpha}\cos{\theta}&\cos{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\cos{\theta}+\sin{\alpha}\sin{\theta} \\
\sin{\alpha \cos{\beta}}&\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\sin{\theta}+\cos{\alpha}\cos{\theta}&\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta}\cos{\theta}-\cos{\alpha}\sin{\theta} \\
-\sin{\beta}&\cos{\beta}\sin{\theta}&\cos{\beta}\cos{\theta}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
From there can you see that the Z coordinate will show up in the resulting vector/matrix multiplication?